# PHP MS_SQL Pagination error with query

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination

Im new to PHP, and even newer to PHP with MS SQL, not MySQL. After doing some research, I came up with what could be considered a pagination query to use, but obviously I'm going wrong somewhere because it throws an error. And I don't understand why.

Heres the Query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Products WHERE SubCatID = '".$scid."' and ProductID NOT IN ( SELECT TOP 0 * FROM Products ORDER BY ProductID ASC ) ORDER BY ProductID ASC
```

Heres the error:

**`Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. (severity 16)`**

I understand it's because of the sub-query, but can anyone just point me in the correct direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must select only one column inside the subquery. Example

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Products WHERE SubCatID = '".$scid."' and ProductID NOT IN ( SELECT TOP 0 ProductID FROM Products ORDER BY ProductID ASC ) ORDER BY ProductID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A better pagination query to use would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Products.*, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductID) AS __RN
    FROM Products WHERE SubCatID = '".$scid."' ORDER BY ProductID
) numberedRows
WHERE __RN BETWEEN 1 and 10
```

You can then substitute the numbers on the last line for the row numbers that you want. Usually, you should not use * though. As it is, you will get an extra column on your result set called `__RN`. If you specify the column names, that won't happen.

Comment: SO does this count the number of rows as well? and if I changed SELECT Products.* to SELECT Products.ProductID, this would make it easier?

Comment: It gives numbers to the rows that you do select. And with the *, you should generally only select the columns that you actually need. Even if you need all of them, you should name them explicitly - this way you will get consistent output even if new columns are added, or the order of existing columns changes.